# trustAsHtml content doesn't encode right

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

just start learning Angular JS.

Now I have two buttons for email and tweet share. I use  tag and defined css for the button style. With `ng-bind-html`, I want to create share links for email and tweet.

Now when mouse hover the button, the text appears in the bottom of browser is correct, but when I click the email button, the title is still correct, but the body content is messed up showing:
**I%20scored%20a%200%%20on%20this%20quiz.%20Try%20to%20beat%20my%20score%20at%20%23**

same as tweet url.

I guess it must be something wrong with the encoding. but why the email title is right?

html:

```
<p>Use links below to challenge your friends.</p>
<div class="share" ng-bind-html="createSharedLinks(percentage)">
</div>
```

js:

```
app.controller('QuizController', ['$scope','$http','$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce){
$scope.percentage = 0;
    $scope.createSharedLinks = function(percentage){
        var url = 'abc.com';

        var emailLink = '<a class="btn email" href="mailto:?subject=Try to beat my quiz score!&amp;body=I scored a '+percentage+'% on this quiz. Try to beat my score at '+url+'">Email a Freind</a>';

        var twitterLink = '<a class="btn twitter" target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=I scored a '+percentage+'% on this quiz. Try to beat my score at&amp;hashtags=SaturnQuiz">Tweet your score</a>';

        var newMarkup = emailLink + twitterLink;

        return $sce.trustAsHtml(newMarkup); //inject new html
    }

}
```

Comment: Suggest you use  directive and template instead

Comment: @charlietfl could you be more specific? I am new to Angular.

Comment: create a directive...is fairly self explanatory. There  are lots of tutorials around about directives

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. In fact the trustAsHtml works as expected. But when you click on the email link, it is the browser that url encodes the query string.

You can use the developer tools to see the actual content.